# mnist database parsing c

Tags: parsing, endianness, mnist

I am trying to parse the MNIST Database of handwritten numbers. However, when I look at the values that it is giving me when I use fread, they aren't right. I have changed the endianness, but the numerical values aren't correct still. Link to the database is here: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

```
int ChangeEndianness(int value) {
    int result = 0;
    result |= (value & 0x000000FF) << 24;
    result |= (value & 0x0000FF00) << 8;
    result |= (value & 0x00FF0000) >> 8;
    result |= (value & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
    return result;
}

FILE *imageTestFiles = fopen("train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz","r");

if(imageTestFiles == NULL) {
    perror("File Not Found");
}
int magic_number_bytes;
fread(&magic_number_bytes, sizeof(int), 1, imageTestFiles);
printf("%d\n", ChangeEndianness(magic_number_bytes));
```

All this is supposed to do is print the "magic number" which is 2049 or 0x00000801, but it instead prints a 529205256 which is 0x1F8B0808. I am sorta new to C, always used Java beforehand. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are aware that the `gz` extension indicates that the data file is *compressed*, and so you first have to decompress it before you can read your data out of it?

Comment: Still doesn't work. The first thing the link says is that the file might be in .gz format when downloaded. I got rid of it when I resaved the file into my coding project, but it still printed the same large number beginning with a 5. So, I just switched it back to .gz because I couldn't tell what was wrong.

Comment: You can find an already decoded version of the MNIST dataset here: http://mnist-decoded.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

The file must first be decompressed rather than simply removing the gz extension.

One can tell your code is operating on a compressed file because `0x1F8B` is the magic number for the gzip file format.

If `xxd` is used to display the file contents after downloading you get the observed `0x1F8B0808`:

```
$ xxd -p train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz | head -c 8
1f8b0808
```

However, if you decompress the file:

```
$ gunzip train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
$ xxd -p train-images-idx3-ubyte | head -c 8
00000803
```

you get the expected magic number for the MNIST data.